# Problems extending Airflow image for Helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'm using HELM to install Airflow in a Kubernetes cluster. I wanted the pods to have an additional apt dependency (sshpass) and as such, I was trying to extend the Airflow image Helm uses and add that apt dependency using Docker. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM apache/airflow:1.10.12-python3.6

USER root

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sshpass \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER airflow
```

I followed the example given by Airflow doc here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/production-deployment.html#extending-the-image, but replaced the image with the one Helm uses.

I then built and published the new image, I made Helm use it by editing the values.yaml file like so:

```
airflow:
  ## configs for the docker image of the web/scheduler/worker
  ##
  image:
    repository: myaccount/myrepo
    tag: mytag
    ## values: Always or IfNotPresent
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    pullSecret: ""
```

I then ran the installation command but the pods that are launched go into CrashLoopBackOff and Error states. I checked the logs of one of the pods which is:

```
*** installing requirements...
Collecting airflow-multi-dagrun==1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/41/e60dff951d002dbf14daf601b1323dfc48c0d24d2bc4e7d19ac72b19c3f6/airflow_multi_dagrun-1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting azure-storage-blob==12.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/dc/3c25aeab827266c019e13abc07f31b5f47d93f1b8548a417c81c89c9d021/azure_storage_blob-12.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326kB)
Collecting azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/e4/15a59108883cc47460b1475aeac935e2d975b5def42f2c0a8b8fd48b3304/azure_cosmosdb_table-1.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
Collecting pandas==1.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/11/e1f53db0614f2721027aab297c8afd2eaf58d33d566441a97ea454541c5e/pandas-1.1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.5MB)
Collecting pyarrow==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/32/34b44246e671a2ba672fc2551dd3a85472ba07e58a75da1dbc655810fbfa/pyarrow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (17.5MB)
Collecting azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0 (from azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/9e/6bb67fe85f6a89d71f50c86a0da778a5064f749a485ed9ba498067034227/azure_core-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
Collecting msrest>=0.6.10 (from azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/f5/9e315fe8cb985b0ce052b34bcb767883dc739f46fadb62f05a7e6d6eedbe/msrest-0.6.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (84kB)
Collecting cryptography>=2.1.4 (from azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/de/7054df0620b5411ba45480f0261e1fb66a53f3db31b28e3aa52c026e72d9/cryptography-3.3.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.6MB)
Collecting azure-common>=1.1.5 (from azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/2b/46ada1753c4a640bc3ad04a1e20b1a5ea52a8f18079e1b8238e536aa0c98/azure_common-1.1.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/c1/24814557f1d22c56d50280771a17307e6bf87b70727d975fd6b2ce6b014a/requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
Collecting azure-cosmosdb-nspkg>=2.0.0 (from azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/0d/1329b47e5386b0acf4e42ada2284851eff60ef3337a87e5b2dfedabbfcb1/azure_cosmosdb_nspkg-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil (from azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
Collecting pytz>=2017.2 (from pandas==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/06/2c2d3034b4d6bf22f2a4ae546d16925898658a33b4400cfb7e2c1e2871a3/pytz-2020.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.15.4 (from pandas==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/32/d3fa649ad7ec0b82737b92fefd3c4dd376b0bb23730715124569f38f3a08/numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.8MB)
Collecting six>=1.6 (from azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/a0/5f06e1e1d463903cf0c0eebeb751791119ed7a4b3737fdc9a77f1cdfb51f/certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.5.0 (from msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/12/b92740d845ab62ea4edf04d2f4164d82532b5a0b03836d4d4e71c6f3d379/requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting isodate>=0.6.0 (from msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/9f/b36f7774ff5ea8e428fdcfc4bb332c39ee5b9362ddd3d40d9516a55221b2/isodate-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/1a/90fa7e7ee05d91d0339ef264bd8c008f57292aba4a91ec512a0bbb379d1d/cffi-1.14.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (401kB)
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2 (from requests->azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/c7/fa589626997dd07bd87d9269342ccb74b1720384a4d739a1872bd84fbe68/chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 (from requests->azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/71/45d36a8df68f3ebb098d6861b2c017f3d094538c0fb98fa61d4dc43e69b9/urllib3-1.26.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (136kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests->azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
Collecting azure-nspkg>=2.0.0 (from azure-cosmosdb-nspkg>=2.0.0->azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/0c/c562be95a9a2ed52454f598571cf300b1114d0db2aa27f5b8ed3bb9cd0c0/azure_nspkg-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.5.0->msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/ce2e7a8fa7c0afb54a0581b14a65b56e62b5759dbc98e80627142b8a3704/oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147kB)
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.1.4->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e7/d9c3a176ca4b02024debf82342dab36efadfc5776f9c8db077e8f6e71821/pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
Installing collected packages: airflow-multi-dagrun, six, chardet, urllib3, idna, certifi, requests, azure-core, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, isodate, msrest, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, azure-storage-blob, azure-common, azure-nspkg,azure-cosmosdb-nspkg, python-dateutil, azure-cosmosdb-table, pytz, numpy, pandas, pyarrow
  The script chardetect is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.6 are installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script plasma_store is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed airflow-multi-dagrun-1.2 azure-common-1.1.26 azure-core-1.10.0 azure-cosmosdb-nspkg-2.0.2 azure-cosmosdb-table-1.0.6 azure-nspkg-3.0.2 azure-storage-blob-12.4.0 certifi-2020.12.5 cffi-1.14.4 chardet-4.0.0 cryptography-3.3.1 idna-2.10 isodate-0.6.0 msrest-0.6.19 numpy-1.19.5 oauthlib-3.1.0 pandas-1.1.2 pyarrow-1.0.1 pycparser-2.20 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.5 requests-2.25.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 six-1.15.0 urllib3-1.26.2
You are using pip version 19.0.2, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
*** installing extra pip packages...
Requirement already satisfied: azure-storage-blob==12.4.0 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (12.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: msrest>=0.6.10 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (0.6.19)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.1.4 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.6 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.18.4 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.5.0 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: isodate>=0.6.0 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.1.4->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4->azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.5.0->msrest>=0.6.10->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.1.4->azure-storage-blob==12.4.0) (2.20)
You are using pip version 19.0.2, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
*** running webserver...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 23, in <module>
    import argcomplete
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'
```

From what I can gather here, it seems that the python dependencies Airflow needs are being installed with the root user (/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages) instead of the airflow user, that is then used to execute airflow that therefore doesn't have said dependencies. Without me trying to extend the Airflow image and just using the default one in Helm chart, the installation python path is /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages and everything else goes well. Why does my custom image behave like this?

Do I need to add anything else to Docker file? Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use `AKS` or `Azure VMs` for your k8s cluster ?
Did you try to install `airflow` using default airflow image, if so did it work correctly without any errors ?

Comment: I use AKS. Hm no I tried straight ahead with helm as it was described in most tutorials I found

Comment: yes using helm :) but did you try to install airflow with default values ? Did it work as expected without errors?

Comment: oh yes it did. If I use the image that comes as default, it works fine

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue on my `AKS` cluster, but it seems to work correctly for me.
For testing purposes I created [bunny96/example-airflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/bunny96/example-airflow) image using your `Dockerfile` - you can test this image as well.

Do you use this [helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow) ?    
Are all your `Pods` in `CrashLoopBackOff` state or specific ones ?     
From which `Pod` are the above logs ?

Comment: Hi. I'm so sorry I took so long to respond. Thank you for your trouble doing all that! Yes I use that Helm Chart. The log file is from the airflow worker. The pods that go into CrashLoopBackOff are the workers. I tried with your image and it works... Weird. What's even weirder is that I tested again with my image and it now works...

Comment: I'm glad it works for you :) . Did you find out what caused the problem ? Are you able to reproduce it ?

Comment: Did you find a solutions for this? I'm running into this same problem..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I didn't realize what was wrong no, it just started to work all of a sudden... But I ended up not needing this. I just needed to install sshpass to connect to a spark cluster using a bash operator, so I'd connect by ssh, give it the password and the spark submit, all in the same command. But I ended up creating a connection to said cluster instead and using SSHOperator with a SSHHook. It's cleaner this way. So I just used helm's default airflow image